# how to call the service(php class) function when clicked on the button on Shopware administration

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I’m new in Shopware6
I’m creating a plugin in which I have created the child menu inside the catalog as an importer and when the user clicks on importer menu it takes the user to a new import page
where I showed the button as an import
and I want to run one of my service (php class) function when clicking on the import button, see the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

I want the sample code to accomplish my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't done so already, create an admin API route with an endpoint that will execute your code. The procedure is the same as [adding a store API route](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/store-api/add-store-api-route#register-route) but you replace `store-api` in the route scope and path with just `api`.

Then in your admin component you can request the endpoint with proper authorization like that, depending on the method used for your route:

```js
const initContainer = Shopware.Application.getContainer('init');
const headers = {
    Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${Shopware.Service(
        'loginService'
    ).getToken()}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

const endpoint = 'api/my/custom/endpoint';
initContainer.httpClient.get(endpoint, { headers });
initContainer.httpClient.post(endpoint, { someParam: true }, { headers });
initContainer.httpClient.patch(endpoint, { someParam: true }, { headers });
initContainer.httpClient.delete(endpoint, { data: { id: '...' }, headers });
```

Comment: Thanks @dneustadt for answering my question, I got your solution and one last thing I want to know that how I can call the JS onclick method and call the component method.

Comment: `import template from './swag-example-overview.html.twig';

Shopware.Component.register('swag-example-overview', {
   template,

    data() {
        return {

        };
    },

    metaInfo() {
        return {
            title: this.$createTitle()
        };
    },

    computed: {
    },

    methods: {
        
    }
});`

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#method-handlers

Comment: Thanks, @dneustadt How can I add the success and failure message after getting the response from the controller?

Comment: I'm getting the 404 error, 
No route found for "GET https://kitchenz-shopware6.ddev.site/api/kit/importer/import" (from "https://kitchenz-shopware6.ddev.site/admin")

Comment: I think the route-scope `administration`. not `admin` ?

Comment: It actually should be just `api` for admin api. I got things mixed up. Fixed it.

Comment: Overall it helps me to call the controller